# Auto-create sheets and populate data from the master sheet

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

I have a sheet named `sample` with the below data.

[image]

```
LOCATION    EMP_ID
INDIA       1234
INDIA       2345
INDIA       3456
USA         4567
USA         5678
```

I need to create sheets automatically based on the location with location name as sheets and populate the data in each sheet corresponding to that location including header.

I tried using some sample code with the help of some websites. I can create sheets automatically without a header and only 1 row per each sheet. If I have more than 1 row for each location, it's throwing an error.

Here is the code that I have tried.

```
Sub CreateTabs()

Dim sheetCount As Integer
Dim sheetName As String
Dim workbookCount As Integer

With ActiveWorkbook
 sheetCount = Sheets("sample").Range("A2").End(xlDown).Row
 For i = 2 To sheetCount Step 1
 sheetName = .Sheets("sample").Range("A" & i).Value
 workbookCount = .Worksheets.Count
 .Sheets.Add After:=Sheets(workbookCount)
 .Sheets(i).Name = sheetName
 .Sheets(i).Range("A2:B2").Value = .Sheets("sample").Range("A" & i, "B" & i).Value
 Next
 End With

Worksheets("sample").Activate

End Sub
```

Appreciate your help in this.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately you have repeated Sheet Name example India 3 times, your code after creating the first sheet INDIA does not check if it is repeated, it continues to create the second INDIA or any repeated location, this creates an error for duplicate sheet name and stop. Correct your code to check names if already exists or try not to repeat location